# Tilting Spaceship left and right in Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sift

I have built a small Space Shooter game like so many other have already :-D and I got everything nailed down except for the tilting images of the Space ship.

I use 3 images - left, center and right - and while I can get the images to turn left and right the problem remains that it only does so when actually touching the left/right side of the screen and the center image never shows at all, which it should if the ship does not move.

Be great if someone could shine a light on that one for me please...

Here is my code for `touchesMoved`:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches{

        let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
        let previousPointOfTouch = touch.previousLocation(in: self)

        let amountDragged = pointOfTouch.x - previousPointOfTouch.x

        if currentGameState == gameState.inGame{
        player.position.x += amountDragged
        }

        if player.position.x > gameArea.maxX - player.size.width/2{
            print("Ship turning Right") //Log print to check if it works
            player.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "playerShipRight")
            player.position.x = gameArea.maxX - player.size.width/2
        }

        if player.position.x < gameArea.minX + player.size.width/2{
            print("Ship turning Left") //Log print to check if it works
            player.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "playerShipLeft")
            player.position.x = gameArea.minX + player.size.width/2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `touchesEnded` to set the ship’s image back to the non-moving centre image,

Comment: I thought of that too, but since I wanna keep touching the screen to shoot continuesly that option is not gonna work for my game mechanics

Comment: OK - then how about using the centre image if `ship.position = pointOfTouch` or if `amountDragged` is 0 or some small value?

Comment: That could work, will try tonight when I get home thanks

Comment: Thanks buddy that worked with a little tinkering, I posted it as an answer so that the case can be closed in the 23 hours!

Comment: @Norvert - no problem, glad to help. I should have really posted my commend as an answer so you could upvote it.:-)

Comment: If you put the answer in the I can green tick it now and that would be even better, then I'll delete my Answer since it was yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from your comments that the ship is firing all the time you touch the screen, so you can't use `touchesEnded` to center the ship because you may not want to move but you still want to shoot.

A simple solution would be to revert to the the center image if `ship.position = pointOfTouch` or if `amountDragged = 0` or some small value.

A more sophisticated approach would be to have an array of perhaps 7 ship textures, representing the ship moving left quickly, medium speed, slowly, stationary, right slowly, right medium speed and right quickly. You could then used `amountDragged` to index into this array for the correct texture.

You could also use `touchesEnded` to implement a 'non-firing, non-moving' texture if you wanted to.